# Oracle subselect not producing error?

Tags: oracle, subquery

Normally we all make posts if there are issues.  This is different where I would expect an error but I'm not getting one.

In Oracle I have the following:

```
create table temp_table as
SELECT PersonID AS OtherName
FROM Personnel
WHERE PersonID = '12345';

1. select FunnyName from temp_table;  -- This produce an error as expected - good.

2. SELECT * FROM Personnel
WHERE PersonID in (select OtherName from temp_table);  --This produces 1 record - good

3. SELECT * FROM Personnel 
WHERE PersonID in (select FunnyName from temp_table);  --This produces all records - bad
```

I would expect statement 3 to also give an error as the subselect is the same as the select in statement 1 that does give an error.  Surely this can't be an Oracle bug, but I don't understand the logic.

I'm using Oracle 11.

Comment: Is statement 2 correct? Or should it have been SELECT * FROM Personnel WHERE PersonID in (select OtherName from temp_table);

Comment: You are correct.  My apologies - will fix.

Comment: Can you post what are the columns in Personal table? Is there any column `FunnyName` in table Personnel ? Query 2 seems to be wrong, it should be select * from Personal table as there is no PersonID column in temp_table.

Comment: Yep, I think San has hit it. If you have a column in Personnel that is named FunnyName (the same as the "non-existing" column of temp_table), then the "select FunnyName from temp_table" actually becomes "select Personnel.FunnyName from temp_table"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce. Here's SQL*Plus output from when I try in HR schema:

```
SQL> create table temp_table
  2  as
  3  select employee_id as other_id
  4  from employees
  5  where employee_id = 100;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> select funny_id
  2  from temp_table;
select funny_id
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "FUNNY_ID": invalid identifier


SQL>
SQL> select employee_id
  2  from employees
  3  where employee_id in (select other_id from temp_table);

EMPLOYEE_ID
-----------
        100

SQL>
SQL> select employee_id
  2  from employees
  3  where employee_id in (select funny_id from temp_table);
where employee_id in (select funny_id from temp_table)
                             *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904: "FUNNY_ID": invalid identifier
```

Do you get the same if you try this in HR sample schema?

---

Following up on the comment from San:

Here's an example:

```
SQL> select employee_id
  2  from employees
  3  where employee_id in (select employee_id from temp_table);

EMPLOYEE_ID
-----------
        100
        101
        102
        103
.....
        203
        204
        205
        206

107 rows selected.
```

And the reason for this behaviour is that in the subquery the parser sees that employee_id is not a column in temp_table, but it *is* a column in employees.

Comment: I've retried it again for the 4th time and now it behaves as expected (and as you mentioned).  I'm not sure how the other 3 tries were different, but I will assume I missed something else.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is- This is not possible in Oracle.

Are you sure you got the results? Can you post your output?

I cant reproduce

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (a number)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 (a)
         VALUES (1)
SELECT * FROM dual
;

select * from table1 where a in (select b from table1);


ORA-00904: "B": invalid identifier : select * from table1 where a in (select b from table1)
```

View [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4f743/2) here

Comment: I've retried it again for the 4th time and now it behaves as expected (and as you mentioned).  I'm not sure how the other 3 tries were different, but I will assume I missed something else.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1208908 You should post all your table structures.